# Vim and Regular Expression: what kind of regex does Vim use?

Tags: regex, testing, vim

Since 6 months I'm using the excellent Vim text-editor.
The most interesting thing is Vim's excellent regex support build-in.

I would like to understand regex better in order to ask less questions here :)

I tried Regex coach, Espresso and other regex-help applications but I found out that even if they are working in these applications it often doesn't work in VIM.
What kind of regex does Vim use?
Are there any help applications in which I can build regex commands for Vim?

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this now: if you compiled vim with `+perl` you can always just do `:perldo s/search/replace/g` and use perl syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know `vim` [uses it's own flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax). Here is what [the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns) says:

> Vim's regexes are most similar to
>   Perl's, in terms of what you can do. 
>   The difference between them is mostly
>   just notation;

If you want a better (more serious) explanation, look up "Traditional NFA" in Mastering Regular Expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry but ViM's regex only vaguely resembles Perl's.  For example, in Perl, to match a plus sign use /\+/  in ViM use /+/  In Perl, all non-alphanumerics are escaped with a backslash.  In ViM, they're mixed.

Comment: vim has a mixed up regex syntax. I would **really, really** like for a way to turn it into egrep’s or better yet, perl’s. In *nvi* you can use `:set extended` to get egrep style so you don’t have to backwhack parens and plusses and such.

Comment: Vim's regex syntax is not only slightly mixed up (i.e., inconsistent backslashing) but it has several different modes.  See `:h magic` for info on the different ways Vim can treat backslashes.

Comment: Vim is hampered a bit by keeping some consistency with traditional Vi syntax, so things can be a bit confusing if coming from a Perl perspective.  As Sitz stated, having a look at `:h magic`.

Comment: [This script](https://github.com/Raimondi/VimRegEx.vim) can help you with testing of Vim's regex and it can help understanding it too.

Answer (score 7):

Vim has several regex modes, one of which is `very magic` that's very similar to traditional regex. Just put `\v` in the front and you won't have to escape as much.

Comment: An example would be very nice

Comment: I can't edit because there are too many pending edits, but here's a basic example: `:%s/\v.+([a-z]+)/\1/g`. This would replace anything up until the first sequence of letters in a line with just the letters.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [eregex.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3282) which translates from PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) to Vim's regex syntax.

This will make it more likely for regexes from other environments to work, because PCRE have become the de facto industry standard: e.g. Java's `java.util.regex`, Python's `re` module, and regexes found in Ruby and JavaScript are all PCREs (each with slight differences).

Comment: I would rather use term “Perl-like” and not “PCRE”. PCRE usually means a library (which is used by PHP, zsh with specific USE flag and `rematchpcre` option or `[[ … -pcre-match … ]]`, grep with specific USE flag and `--perl-regexp`/`-P` option). Python and JavaScript do not use it, most likely neither does Java. I bet you will see major differences in supported escape sequences (e.g. `\p{}`, `\x{}`, `\cx`, `\X`, `\N` and many others), `\Q…\E` also are not so common. These are supported by PCRE and Perl, but not by python or javascript (except for `\x{}` and `\cx`).

Comment: eregex is exactly what I was looking for. Basically adds the opportunity to use perl-like regexes instead of Vim's own flavour