# In Vim, how do you search for a word boundary character, like the \b in regexp?

Tags: regex, vim

I'd like to be able to search

```
/the\b
```

to find **"the"** but not **"then"**.

I also tried searching with [very magic](https://davitenio.wordpress.com/tag/very-magic-mode/) turned on:

```
/\vthe\b
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`/the\>`

See [`:help /ordinary-atom`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fordinary-atom)

I assume "regexp" means [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions). It is worth noting that Vim's regex syntax differs from (and apparently predates) PCRE.

See also:

- [Why does VIM have its own regex syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax/3604643#3604643)
- [What's the difference between vim regex and normal regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864467/whats-the-difference-between-vim-regex-and-normal-regex)
- [Within vim's regex engine, why are some metacharacters escaped and some are not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998913/within-vims-regex-engine-why-are-some-metacharacters-escaped-and-some-are-not#13999104)
- [Can I make vim accept \b rather than just \< and \>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081331/can-i-make-vim-accept-b-rather-than-just-and/33081758#33081758)

Comment: why wouldn't \b work?  vim doesn't conform to regex?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. Vim's regex syntax predates PCRE. I added links to related questions.

Comment: "regexp" does not mean PCRE. It is simply a synonym to "regex".

Answer (score 104):

Use `\<` and `\>` for word start and word end, respectively.

E.g. In your specific case you would use:

```
/the\>/
```

Comment: The reason I always forget this and always have to come back to this page is because I forget that it is a BACKSLASH, because you are inserting a special character: a word boundary. I tend to type a forward slash because I am used to that as an escape sequence, then I can't figure out why it's not working. Hopefully this will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 46):

If `very magic` is turned on, then you shouldn't escape the `>` character. See what's [magic search](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic).
SO in your case you'd do:

```
/\v<the>
```

it would search for only the word 'the'.

Answer (score 18):

if you are trying to search a word at your cursor. you can just hit <kbd>*</kbd>, or <kbd>#</kbd> for backward search.

Comment: This unfortunately ignores the sigil. (If you use it on $var, it will match "var", not "$var"). I understand why-- $ is not a word character. But looking for precise variable names is one of the most common reasons I search.