# Within vim's regex engine, why are some metacharacters escaped and some are not?

Tags: regex, unix, vim, history, vi

Why do you have to escape some metacharacters in their regex engine, but not others? For example:

```
/foo[1-9]*
```

works as expected, but the regular expression

```
foo[1-9]+
```

must be expressed as

```
/foo[1-9]\+
```

in vim. Anybody know?

Comment: I can't tell you why, but [here is a list](http://vimregex.com/#metacharacters) of which ones to escape if you need it. I would imagine though that it's some kind of backward compatibility thing. That in the beginning only a few meta-characters were supported and everything else was literals. And then they added the other meta-characters, but still wanted old patterns (which might include `+` as a literal) to work. So all new ones have to be escaped. But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Backwards comparability with new regex metacharacters would make sense. I'm curious as to why they didn't just force users to comply after regex got fairly standardized if that is the case.

Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because vim (actually **vi**) created their own regex flavor long before perl did. Even POSIX BRE and ERE came after vim<sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX)</sup>. They are still maintaining their own flavor so it's quite different.

To make the answer more resourceful here is a quote from [`ed`'s wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29).

> The editor was originally written in PDP-11/20 assembler in **1971** by Ken Thompson. **Many features of ed came from the qed** from his alma mater University of California at Berkeley[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) Thompson was very familiar with qed, and had reimplemented it on the CTSS and Multics systems. **His versions of qed were the first to implement regular expressions**. **Although regular expressions are part of ed, their implementation is considerably less general than that in qed.**
>
> **Aspects of ed went on to influence ex**, **which in turn spawned vi**. The non-interactive Unix command grep was inspired by a common special uses of qed and later ed, where the command **g/re/p means globally search for the regular expression re and print the lines containing it**. The Unix stream editor, sed implemented many of the scripting features of qed that were not supported by ed on Unix. In turn sed influenced the design of the programming language AWK - which inspired aspects of Perl.

These two paragraphs have a lot of information! I wish I could bold it all. Some highlights,

- Ken Thompson wrote `ed` in 1971. `ed` was actually a reimplentation of `qed`.
- Ken added Regular Expression in his version of `qed` which is actually `ed`.
- Inspired by `ed`, in 1976 William Joy (known as Bill Joy) wrote `ex`<sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29)</sup>
- Bill Joy in 1976 wrote `vi` as the visual mode for a line editor called `ex` <sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)</sup>
- `grep` was inspired by special uses of `qed` and later `ed`.
- `sed` was implemented as many of the scripting features of qed that were not supported by ed on Unix
- `sed` influenced the design of `awk`.

So vi Regular Expression were in `ed` which was written in 1971. It's long before any other regular expression flavor.

Comment: Ah, I see. Huh. I always thought POSIX ERE was the hard and fast standard for regex and never knew that it came in different flavors until today. It seems like it, with pages like [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) which should more appropriately be prefaced with a big "THIS GUIDE APPLIES TO POSIX ERE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS ONLY." Thanks for the answer man!

Comment: Update my answer a little bit. See the timeline you'll get a lot of idea.