# VIM or sed to remove a line that contains only a date with BRE of [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I cannot seem to figure out how to delete these lines.

In VIM, I tried the following and it did not execute:

```
:%s/[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/d
```

Then I get this error: pattern not found.

I can do the following and get results:

```
egrep '[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}' file
```

This prints out:

```
2006-12-18
2007-02-05
2007-02-13
2007-03-06
2007-03-13
2007-04-03
2007-04-15
2007-04-16
2007-04-24
2007-05-18
2007-06-14
2007-07-15
2008-05-14
2008-05-20
2008-06-03
2008-06-10
2008-06-11
2008-06-19
2008-06-25
2008-07-15
2008-07-21
2009-10-21
2010-07-02
```

In VIM, I tried adding a `^` to the beginning of the pattern and a `$` to the end and it still did not recognize the pattern.

I am using VIM on Mac 10.11.2 (15C50) El Capitan using Terminal.

sed gives me issues as well. I tried:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}$/d' file
```

I get the error:

```
sed: 1: "file": command c expects \ followed by text
```

I tried sed with or without `-i`, using `"sed 's/pattern//g' file"`, and `sed -e`, but none of these did anything to the file.

I also tried replacing `[0-9]` with `[:digit:]`, but that did not work either:

```
sed -i '/[:digit:]{4}\-[:digit:]{2}\-[:digit]{2}/d' file
```

The results were the following error:

```
sed: 1: "file": command i expects \ followed by text
```

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim, I think you have the wrong things escaped, and are using the wrong command - s is for substitution, not to run line delete commands; try

```
:g/\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}/d
```

(You can use `[0-9]` but `\d` seems neater - and `:help \d` says it's faster)

Comment: @technerdius it is not **like** magic, it **is** `magic`, vim's `magic`

Comment: and should be noted, `\d` will **not** work with `BRE`, **not** work with `ERE` either. But it will work with `PCRE`

Comment: It worked on a Mac El Capitan Terminal. So, I guess that is PCRE. Thank you for that information.

Comment: I don't know what @Kent is trying to note, but Vim regexes aren't PCRE, BRE or ERE, they come down from a time before those existed ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999104/478656 ). Since you said BRE in the title, and mentioned 'sed', maybe it looks like you wanted a BRE-compatible regex, and `\d` in my answer is not compatible with that (I'm not that familiar with the differences, personally).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that is what I meant. `\d` works for vimregex, but it (`\d -> [0-9]`) is not supported by `BRE`. Since OP mentioned BRE in question.

Answer (score 3):

- You have known `BRE`, then you should escape `{` to give it special meaning.
- `sed` uses BRE as default,  but you can add `-r` (gnu sed) to let sed work with `ERE`, then your regex should work.
- `-` is not a special char in regex, (unless it sits between `[...]`), so you don't need escape it
- with vim, default `magic` setting is `magic`, so you need escape `{` as well
- what you can do in vim to save those escaping is: `:%s/\vpattern....` the `\v` will let `:%s/../../` work with `very magic`. `:h magic` to know details.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, if I ran `sed '/[0-9]\{4}-[0-9]\{2}-[0-9]\{2}/d' file', would that delete this pattern globally or on the first string? If only the first string, should I add the `g' to the front like VIM such as `sed 'g/[0-9]\{4}-[0-9]\{2}-[0-9]\{2}/d' file'? Thank you!!!

Comment: @technerdius first of all, your pattern(regex) is not correct. You should escape `}` as well. The sed line will remove the line containing the pattern. You can test and see the result actually.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thank you.

Comment: I created a test file called testsed.txt. I contained only those dates and a line at the end `test text.' I used `sed -i.bk '/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/d' testsed.txt'. Strangely, it did not work with just `-i'. I had to include the `.bk' in order for it to work.

Comment: @technerdius very likely you were using bsd sed.