# Can I make vim accept \b rather than just \< and \>?

Tags: regex, vim, conventions

I've just read this:

[In Vim, how do you search for a word boundary character, like the \b in regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404349/in-vim-how-do-you-search-for-a-word-boundary-character-like-the-b-in-regexp)

and I was wondering - can't I make vim recognize `\b` also, somehow?

Comment: No, Vim uses its own regular expression engine with its own syntax, where `\b` already has its own meaning: "backspace".

Comment: Have a look at [*Perl compatible regular expressions*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions) at Vim Tips Wiki.

Comment: @stribizhev: Make that an answer, I think. Although it won't work for me, since on Fedora 20 (blech) vim is compiled with `-perl`.

Comment: One thing to note: if you use `\v` to make your regex "very magic", then you can use `<` and `>` instead of `\<` and `\>`, which is slightly more convenient, and in general makes the Vim regexps feel a bit more Perl-like. The [Loupe plugin](https://github.com/wincent/loupe) can be used to make `\v` the default.

Answer (score 8):

Since Vim's regex flavor treats `\b` as a backspace character, and there is no chance re-defining this shorthand construct, you can only make it work with a PCRE regex engine that can be used with Vim the way described at [Perl compatible regular expressions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions) Vim Tips Wiki.

This is the description from that page:

> 1. Verify with `:ver` that `+perl` or `+perl/dyn` is compiled in.
> 2. Install Perl if necessary. On Windows, ActivePerl is standard but any dependency-free perl58.dll will work if you don't need any other perl modules. If you don't want a full install of perl, copy perl58.dll from [Strawberry Perl 5.8.x](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) into the folder vim.exe lives and the commands below will work.
> 3. Type `:perldo s/searchme/replaceme/g`
>
> Note: `+perl/dyn` doesn't seem to be necessary.

Or if Ruby is compiled in, Ruby's regex can be used, too to recognize `\b` as a word boundary:

> Or if you have ruby compiled in (look for `+ruby` in `:ver` output)
>
> Equivalent to `s/pattern/replacement/g`:
>
> `:rubydo gsub /pattern/,'replacement'`

Comment: Which is _almost_ as easy as `%!perl -lpe 's/pattern/replacement/g'`. :)