# Pcre (*SKIP) in Vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim, pcre

Is there a `(*SKIP)` equivalent in the Vim regex engine? (without using `:perldo` etc)

Comment: Please add more details on your issue, perhaps, you can do without the (*SKIP) verb. Still, [you can use PCRE in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33081758/3832970).

Comment: As said already, I don't want to use any other regex engines. I just want to know whether there is a (*SKIP) equivalent in vim.   (It is not about a particular issue but let's take for example the "famous" regex pattern 'not this(*SKIP)(?!)|but this'

Comment: try reading `:help pattern`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to [how do skip or f work on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex), it's only implemented in PCRE.

The answer explains that this can be implemented in other ways, especially since Vim has variable-length lookbehind. So `/not this(*SKIP)(?!)|but this/` could be formulated in Vim as this:

```
/^\%(.*not this\)\@!.*\zsbut this/
```

I don't have a general recipe to translate `(*SKIP)` into Vim's regexp dialect, but it should be possible to express any such expression in Vim, too (but the resulting regexp may not be as tidy and have repetitive information).

Comment: `(*SKIP)` is [implemented in perl too](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(*SKIP)-(*SKIP%3aNAME))

Comment: I also think 'No' is the correct answer. I haven't accepted your answer yet because your example `/^\%(.*not this\)\@!.*\zsbut this/` doesn't seem to work. Could you please check?

Comment: @Vimminator: The pattern matches `but this` in lines that do not contain `not this` (i.e. not before and not after). What else it is supposed to match?

Comment: Understand, you took my "pattern" example (almost) literally. Here is a "real" example (taken from the great rexegg site): `{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(?!)|\b\w+\b`. This selects all words not surrounded by curly braces (assuming there are no nested curly braces).

Comment: I have accepted the answer although the part 


`/not this(*SKIP)(?!)|but this/` could be formulated in Vim as this: `/^\%(.*not this\)\@!.*\zsbut this/`

is not really correct. The answer would have been better if Ingo removed that part :-)

Comment: @Vimminator: Thanks, I appreciate that! I've added a caveat that the example isn't a general solution; unfortunately, I cannot give such.