# Remove all occurence of _[number].htm in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I've a file with occurence in the form `_[number].htm`, for example  `_43672151820.htm`

How I can remove all occurrences of strings with a matching pattern?

Answer (score 2):

**Substitute substring**

Use this regular expression with the substitution command `%s`

```
:%s/_\d\+\.htm//g
```

Explanation (from regex101.com):

```
_ matches the character _ with index 9510 (5F16 or 1378) literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\+ matches the character + with index 4310 (2B16 or 538) literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
htm matches the characters htm literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags 
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

**Substitute word**

The above regular expression will match for instance `123.htm` in `ab_123.htm`. If you want to match a word use vim's *word boundaries*`\<` and `\>`:

```
:%s/\<_\d\+\.htm\>//g
```

(see [In Vim, how do you search for a word boundary character, like the \b in regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404349/in-vim-how-do-you-search-for-a-word-boundary-character-like-the-b-in-regexp))