# vim: how to find words by matching first part, remove first part and then add a string to the end of word

Tags: vim, find-replace

In our code, we have non-standard naming conventions for our variables. For example, we have a category identifier that are attached to many variables in a file, like: `usa_foo`, `bar_usa`, where `usa` is the category identifier. I'd like to convert all these names with a standard of placing the category id in the end, so `usa_foo` would turn into `foo_usa`. Since these variables are often embedded in expressions, they could be followed by a few possible characters, which in this case (hashicorp hcl language), are mostly `"`, `]`,  `,` or whitespace. For example, I'd like to turn:

```
usa_foo = something
something "${var.usa_foo}"
b = [var.usa_foo, var.bar_usa]
bar_usa
```

into:

```
foo_usa = something
something "${var.foo_usa}"
b = [var.foo_usa, var.bar_usa]
bar_usa
```

I know how to do find and replace if I know the character that follows the word, say `"`. Then it would be

```
%s/usa_\(\w*\)"\(.*\)/\1_usa"\2/g
```

However, I'm not sure how I can match multiple ending characters and still do the same thing.

Comment: vim has [`\>` as a character for word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404349/in-vim-how-do-you-search-for-a-word-boundary-character-like-the-b-in-regexp). Does that give you enough information?

Comment: that works. Thanks @jeremysprofile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vim, how do you search for a word boundary character, like the \b in regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404349/in-vim-how-do-you-search-for-a-word-boundary-character-like-the-b-in-regexp)

Answer (score 1):

Using very magic to avoid backslash

```
:%s/\v(usa)(_)(foo)/\3\2\1

\v ................... very magic
() ................... regex group with no backslash
```

NOTE: We keep the second group in the middle, just exchange 1 for 3

Of course, if you have other occurrences at the same line you should add `/g`