# Add missing spaces after commas

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I try to change

```
rest.get = function(url,onsuccess,onerror) {
      rest.askServer("GET", url, null,200,onsuccess,onerror);
};
```

into

```
rest.get = function(url, onsuccess, onerror) {
      rest.askServer("GET", url, null, 200, onsuccess, onerror);
};
```

I thought this command would work:

```
:%s/,(\S)/, \1/g
```

But it doesn't.

**Why ?** What command should I use ?

Comment: Please note that this question isn't about doing it outside of vim.

Comment: `:%s/,\(\S\)/, \1/g` should work.

Comment: Because there are a zillion different dialects for regular expressions, and Vim's is only one of them.  See `:help pattern-searches`, and in particular `:help /magic` and subsequent sections.  Read them patiently.

Comment: @SatoKatsura +1 for zillion dealects for regexes. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use capturing group:

```
%s/,\(\S\)/, \1/g
```

`\(\S\)` is being used to capture the next non-space character after a comma.

OR you can avoid the capturing using **positive lookahead**:

```
:%s/,\(\S\)\@=/, /g
```

Or to avoid the escaping using **very magic**:

```
:%s/\v,(\S)\@=/, /g
```

Comment: Why do I need to escape the parenthesis around the group ?

Comment: By default `vim`'s regex engine requires `(` and `)` to be escaped, which can be avoided using `\v`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I see. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic

Answer (score 4):

Use `:%s/,\(\S\)/, \1/g`.

You should escape parenthesis as noted in vim documentation. Consider this wiki entry: [Search and replace in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace#Details).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
:%s/,\zs\ze\S/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and `:%s/,(\S)/, \1/g` solution wasn't working for me (I was using vscode with vim key mappings). I used a *positive lookahead* instead to isolate the `,` to substitute for `,<space>` using

```
:%s/,(?=\S)/, /g
```

[regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) was super helpful for this

Comment: Do note that this regex is not strictly vim-compatible: it would have to be re-written to use vim’s positive lookahead syntax for use in vim. I’m sure it works in vscode just fine though.