# What is the name of vim's regex engine?

Tags: regex, vim

Honestly, I find Regex a nightmare mainly due to the [variety of engines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html#:%7E:text=The%20syntax%20and%20behavior%20of%20a%20particular%20engine%20is%20called%20a%20regular%20expression%20flavor.%20This%20tutorial%20covers%20all%20the%20popular%20regular%20expression%20flavors%2C%20including%20Perl%2C%20PCRE%2C%20PHP%2C%20.NET%2C%20Java%2C%20JavaScript%2C%20XRegExp%2C%20VBScript%2C%20Python%2C%20Ruby%2C%20Delphi%2C%20R%2C%20Tcl%2C%20POSIX%2C%20and%20many%20others.#:%7E:text=As%20usual%20in%20the%20software%20world%2C%20different,Delphi%2C%20R%2C%20Tcl%2C%20POSIX%2C%20and%20many%20others.) available to Regex. However, knowing the engine and flavor names of a particular application helps me figure out what syntax I must follow.

For instance, [Visual Studio uses the .NET engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Visual%20Studio%20uses%20.NET%20regular%20expressions%20to%20find%20and%20replace%20text.). What is the name of vim's regex engine?

edit: As @Matt and @phd explained, flavor != engine. Vim has its own engine, but it has four flavors: `nomagic`, `magic`, `very nomagic`, `very magic`.

Comment: It is Vim's regex engine.

Comment: Regexp flavor != regexp engine. Vim has one flavor but two different engines.

Comment: @Matt vim has [4 flavors](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) — nomagic, magic, very nomagic, very magic. Magic is the recommended setting.

Comment: @Matt so what is the difference between flavor and engine?

Comment: @RubemPacelli Roughly speaking, "flavor" is "regex.compile" and "engine" is "regex.exec".

Comment: @Matt So the regex syntax is defined by the flavor, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. This community was sick. Just gave you one vote back. (and going to be replaced by chatgpt soon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not an expert in this topic, but i think my research can be helpful.

What I have found so far is that Vim has it's own RegEx engine and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax)
can be informative for you, because there are some explanations to why Vim has it's own engine.

Also on this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines) you can find what features are supported in Vim.

Hope that I could help you a bit.