# Vim Regex to replace tags

Tags: vim, regex

I am lookin for a regex express to remove the email addresses from a text file.

Input file:

```
Hannah Churchman <xxxx@xxxxxxxx.com>; Julie Drew <xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>;
```

Output file:

```
Hannah Churchman; Julie Drew;
```

I thought a generic regex shuch as s/<(.*?)>//g  would be a good starting point but I am unable to find the right expression for use Vim?

something like

```
:%s/ <\(.*?\)>//g
```

does not work. Error is "E486: Pattern not found:".

```
:%s#[^ <]*>##g   almost works but it leaves  the space and < behind.
:%s# <##g  to remove the " <" remaining stuff.
```

Any tips on how to better craft this command?

Comment: `.*?` is not a non-greedy match in vim, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1305957/155299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this regex on your sample and it seems to work: `:s/\s<[^\>]*>//g`