# How to use non-greedy in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, greedy, regex-greedy

Input

```
\sn{1}\gn{2}\gn{3}\sn{4}\sn{5}\gn{6}\gn{7}\sn{8}\yr{2012}
```

Required output

```
\sn{1}\sn{4}\yr{2012}
```

I used this code. but failed.

```
%s/\\sn{\([^}]*\)}.*\\sn{\([^}]*\)}.*\\yr/\sn{\1}\sn{\2}\yr{\3}/gec
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my match non greedy in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the non-greedy in vimregex is `.\{-}` Take a look `:h \{-` for details.

So your `:s` cmd could be written in :

```
%s/\(\\sn{[^}]*}\).\{-}\(\\sn{[^}]*}\).\{-}\(\\yr{[^}]*}\).*/\1\2\3/g
```