# Quite confused about `\?` in vim's regex

Tags: regex, vim

I'we been trying to do simple substitution in vim, and find out that the `\?` in vim not works with `*` or `+`, saying that `(NFA regexp) Can't have a multi follow a multi`, in the vim:

```
i want it to stop here, not here
~
~
~
[NORMAL] ...
:%s/^\(.*\?\)here//
```

If I remove `\?` it works, but the it regex matches up to 2nd `here`.

But with normal regex it works: https://regex101.com/r/iHdxxl/1

Why it isn't possible to use `\?` with `*` or `\+` in vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim), you can't add the `?` char in vim after the asterisk.
To make the search non greedy, you need to use `.\{-}` instead of `.*`:

```
:%s/\(.\{-}\)here//
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use negative lookahead:

```
:%s/\v^((here)@!.)* here//
```

`\v` is used for **very magic** to avoid escaping all over in regex.