# How to replace a string between subsequent occurrence of 2 string pattern in Shell scripting?

Tags: shell, sed, vi

I have a file that has several lines like:

```
"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"
```

In the `vi` editor or using `sed` I want to replace all the text between `":"` and `","` with `","`, i.e. I want to keep all keys and remove all the values.

The line will become like:

```
"key1","key2","key3","key4"
```

In `vi` editor I tried to use `:%s/":".*","/","/g`, and using `sed` I used `sed 's/":"*","/","/'` but instead of replacing the in-between text, it is removing all the text from the first occurrence of `":"` and last occurrence `","`,i.e. the line is becoming `"key1","key4":"val4"`.

How do I replace the text in-between subsequent occurrences of `":"` and following `","` ?

Comment: `.*` is a monster because `.` matches anything and `*` is greedy. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate JSON? Like [this](https://jqplay.org/s/WzL18JUPiy)?

Comment: Assuming keys cannot contain `:` and values cannot contain `"`: `:%s/:"[^"]*"//g` or `:%s/":"[^"]*//g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that neither the key nor value can contain `"`, this **sed** solution will work:

```
   sed 's/\("[^"]*"\):"[^"]*"/\1/g'
```

Explanation:

- `s/` substitute
- `/\("[^"]*"\):"[^"]*"/` search for `"stuff":"more stuff"`, where it is assumed there are no other double-quotes `"` in `stuff`, etc., and then capture the first part (with `\(` and `\)`)
- `/\1/` keep only the first part
- `/g` and continue

Comment: **Edit:** If the key or value _can_ contain a double-quote `"`, this solution may be easily modified, once you tell us how the `"` is escaped. (And how the escape is escaped!)