# Vim non-greedy search \{-}

Tags: regex, vim

What difference is there between `*` and `\{-}` in Vim?

In particular, can one match something the other can't?

Why would one use `{-}` over `*`?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/199) and/or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1305853/9758194)

Comment: @phd No, these show how to solve _a_ problem using non-greedy. I am asking whether there is something that can be done with non-greedy that _can't_ be accomplished with other approaches (eg `[^<anti-token>]*` instead of `<token>*`), or is _significantly_ more unwieldy.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305859/13534897) answer solves the non-greedy problem, even with just as many characters.

Comment: The [question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582669/5889131) should help explain. Reluctant (non-greedy) searches vs greedy ones are less about what they can and cannot match and more about how fast they are. Unoptimized regex can be quite slow over certain strings; reluctant searches can help with that immensely in certain situations.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319996/13534897) answers most of my question, in particular why one would choose `{-}` over `*`, but not whether they can _always_ match what the other can.

Comment: Just pointing out that the linked questions have still not answered their difference in power/convenience/speed (a few answers mention that non-greedy can be faster, but nothing concrete); they all answer the qualitative difference.